Reading and Writing more than 4096 bytes to and from STDIN
I'm trying to implement a here document like the one used in bash (in C), but I noticed that I can't give it a line that's longer than 4096 bytes, I looked it up and It was because of the max size of the Kernel I/O queues so my process never receives the full input that I type in the shell. Meanwhile the bash's heredoc can handle that. is there a way to get around this using C.
with any word that exceeds 4096 characters only the 4096 characters gets printed or the input gets corrupted
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    ssize_t r_bytes;
    char buf[42];
    while (r_bytes = read(0, buf, 42))
    {
        write(1, buf, r_bytes);
    }
    return (0);
}

1-Compile and execute this code.
2-Give it this input:
<start>herrslcrwhjsyxlnuvxoofkmnnqnqplyyomfekjdvifzmzqsjjffjlqgvxrmhplzfaywnsptodrwygvhtplduhivfefqefkwcrficiatatbvlpzikietxdfekfnqvgazseylfagktlaseeedbbeajmnvshwkzvlfyhdoswwzzdesnaphprclhihfdckjcpepytllszcucuyvgqlfreyknejkjbthgociqxzellhzgdqkpnglnaocygxqifkjikcrepkcosxclwqlhhgzndoqroocniwrjaoumuvlvtvdrsyaupmkldzhvurnzgwhpvsyzrqzxgtlythlqflciocyepzbxyepegfxifkuopqrivsnhzqhmjmbrdkoxwrgpmdntoqlksjxwrfdadkjzjvyknulhlhmseykfpqnpvfpfbxncefcbfzdfndkwskdusuhylklqcxnmbibgmerllmzgmorqpqawbiexnbgkuaxbiucrkfsxndhdifgrfiuyanximidvvfaqnurmsnvfnwahuvpyjjvpukbrkemqotmvnvqcwivueqisxqvrfunmaaeuguqpullxgyuypepxgkrmgpfxlihmazubjmnlifqoyfidhpvvpyraddjlxoalrhsrpviqkhmcszkluelumfpukwynrmlhdvnwhhukorlpqzouzakphkgorumfqabjxrtghrvynqazsoahewbhpujofcokzeapdlpkgzrrdnmmwintaoowbzctqnxatvfecwnirxaacqmsrbecdgikauqosygzyxkyfikryohidyslrizbwnnhbiwnqbbgqylhvkmtnazfdzvweucoqdovuzfuqlywxdfkmzgsssnprekjfnutlmhbdvtcngeitphqywvtmppptaxyielehppdxjgzuvwybjealhkjjlgibgjcysgvmgfvgqpnpmadtjlngmsxgvolvdlzkfyfqoujjiegunytjkxornyruaxgpqqjhqyfwymvyglnccfbdslqdbrqpmwtonklsajnuaemvkqwjuscectjwbvohfvuecltlkhszplqxipaymbtxjztjofubjblqrrantnfcsoirrvkwnvmwnwqpdsysqsokmwylnvvryhnaatnlbmvtfhbquzmnrukbvqbvwjdqrdgthrqpnjebcokbroruogaswulugwxkrrmbrkskqhlgbufanzafdsbgcqcjxntmczmzrsjqjfcpmetvjirmcpmfmobfslagzlvoppuachoyxbrgqejrdbykeczesigwwcmjdmvvzudouderjbhpihwaxhizaxejmckwnwgmhcgylephrukykldufcobjqrmiiqnxznmlnzpdbxgyxfnwdtgjeupvxdnzyvivpuvrfulypwzfgxmnomohfcvcyuhimpeelkwaurwcgcthvsfpppurrercewdfhryyyytzowizhtlzohewpqxjmacpgkhvjzopuoggswmowcbfhkdpkvbjajqjmqfqbovgiaojsfyaqzqmngemgytcsvsqfdpbcehxrcleqmguhnuipoqecwralfehnxrevtmgqbiqpfighujwpgqqfcumppeamwasfqkeochbptmezrmttngijtwawvojpmpkzozkkxzuxzggvcswowkjmtvtmzwptwolaflkddwbkmzxvnclqzsikajmyihcatjrnvqixbfnmpvigmmwmepppebohsidrquffvkmjxtuchozqbdcowfqpnrhxzrkxozpqfojuybxwcerlfmaveslyfnkvkphotyrdukcelzszlqaqyayvuzljfsgrltqherbwabxslbwxlrfnundvzvchgpllcenakkwaejdejpfqiarsomxgcoplpdrqdudcaopdxjziyvuqeolkqqopwzixmhpyaabjuoplqourpuzphjfyvvwoxlssgkkqrwewzikvkdgfwgtzkennzhlnuakywfiiwqvpsfqgkowunzfblrxiwqibulojvrjnbhgjookrazjzrhmhqxnxjmaupdczcwlhmhvaepgvdksckettpzqhkfbmszbqbqidnjnwcrloqduucjdgvisrlixrwsqtdrackbbwbfslpgrkycycqnbccebvcuivfkyejwwcfpuaqmuacfrcbjtmvwvcryuzlbvuwagcggiwwzxxbicvnwbafuubeqjuvrdcizwbnagdntjypfolexpesovyrupoxlnhtdcnhyppxoniqdpsfyhlarshtdgwbtbkjtklvdpztdumykphalytjaefwfhwhhnpqcwfcruhmmxoqngnvtfbxwfmfdkhivhitsdecqehowjmgxmdipdtsiwuxivdjmmwrkotqrdhwtnzfbhemboqkqkodaabxkedzkpxriuurifgfjhrtxpqlaoolqgbkdqyaatgnsdzhawpfhvwgtqjsdeopuwvgolouofwwzbhpeybvpglwwqjcjlqpsobgojoijblingffcrsydqcjjzlwoeklhxzecitrtihakcktvfnfblmhejybnsihzhmcgxayxoruyvnecnbbfpwieoejtfzjhjczduuldcflvwzjzruxlckvpyivtnyzfzdhfzptwjjggaeqsbgkkynqjpsuobflnaqbwayslrsvrgrbtjzhkbtmvicoxbdfexnuwzbvamumswnloymrjojujwtmcudbhcxvbxbcwzrzhjlrgoerptgczhldyskvqpqxxpuywrtltwyzkbpdmzgcaulbdygqfeoflgwnhtuaelesgjaawskmsccgyoqraabxppuueyfbdvuhvotgbswrtyfxliwkewxzpoetubihymgbmqnmaseemmonsgkbfsomawfjgxqqrjbfxpyissubkeafseucdpwasafhkkhsdygbgeypjesxeyafbdctkgorlcknmjtnqpjbkwwyztqailtefgjmkgujpynkfmtqnjvdqjgttnvejsvzahddzedysitrwumidnufktcozdfgshwzicuykokdjxszhcsimalzijyvylkaxdweafmtfgtkaepteyafqijbonhgxrqnkxwtpceajseopimpkvouzajzrrtbpiymsqxnrkmpejokpancnmmcincaddywnozsknikimutldarwabrzgvymatbamsbwaikbwatvqbpvfsdeafycximswbehmyzwzarqvcjtzyofhfjxagtrehvssqsbtowueuizqjuyjrulldgxtjtkirekhwaxhdfcnbwhyqtuinxpxddkvoiveoenwsgixpqqxupuunrgyddowemsegsovkigdwxgefzvmiuuafynnxukixpsnmiwszojlmcxvopwdazpcuxetclgatgzmvmeecppggaqhobatlyynzhdygxiatrktpgntmkqcjkuxmdlroounnxcebepchuokotvmqfctmtjsnplgjmeobzbwhxekvlbknvwughuppzuecumvqjylqkhlmpbbhmgrenotwyyquqhgrrboqvjskaczyhnukqogmqbngkrvsakcppveykzuqmsbxdfxjulofmpnilynqzzgdxbdjjzhskrthbwzjzugjsutgpgkromaccbjqitrhxlahzaygcvztjycifokrbxugvdmwxqqxibhgckxwhabbjsmnpencsplrxjnfanqtdgrruiomesapwfdvsotvkgqgfxeelavujnigyedrhwksraopenosfgbrdvogtudmxecvrvxvjjuaodjvajlgazeqsyemyysxpnilklpvzciwidtjebaczuhezsresvglzivbbodxakeighfawfanvdzzpadrcisfsqyhfbuyurppqdfekrolbzxvquulxhnwwndndirrcysbywooygizgbuiezholvuoqkyiorttcmzpseippnxkuilfsrxfknzkvzlqmdlupqkxdjxtiuxjghikocnpkocoauecaofnsyouizpbgvytkpxrfalhvpqymbxqetmozufwmcbycsalporhqzlfpbeqgffteuqeatujlrjyjhjjjhj<end>helloworld

and the output is everything until the <end> or a 4096 charater string that is corrupted.

Maybe it's a shell limitation. But anyway, are you typing 4097 characters into the terminal? Are you piping a file into your executable? Please [edit] and tell us more. What exactly are you doing?

According to the man page for the read function: On Linux, read() (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
systems.). You need to provide more details about your tests when you try to read 4096 bytes.

When using read you most probably want to check that you read > 0 characters. Note that it may return -1 in which case you will try to write size_t(-1) bytes which is a lot and will access your buf out of bounds.

@EricPostpischil I know the code is generally correct but in the case of let's say 5000 character text you'll notice that it will only read 4096 character no matter what the input is or the buffer size is. sorry for the confusion.

@AnassAbidar: I do not notice such a behavior. Stop describing the allegedly non-working code and instead provide an exact copy of it. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Also provide a complete description of the input you provide and the output observed so that another person can exactly reproduce the problem.

I suspect your actual problem is not “the max size of the Kernel I/O queues” but that your terminal software is not accepting lines longer than 4096 characters.

Redirect the output to a file and compare that new file with your original file.

@EricPostpischil no, it is indeed because of the pseudoterminal buffer capacity, independent from the actual terminal software

@Ctx: The pseudoterminal buffer capacity is part of the terminal software. Still not a limitation in “the max size of the Kernel I/O queues”.

@EricPostpischil If the linux pty driver is part of the terminal software, then yes.

@Ctx: Of course it is. It is software, not hardware, and it makes the terminal interface work.

@Ctx: How do you know it is the pseudoterminal? If a terminal application creates a pseudoterminal, accepts plenty of keystrokes from the keyboard, and writes, say, 10,000 bytes to the pseudoterminal to be read by the connected stream, why wouldn’t the pseudoterminal take bytes until its buffer is full (leaving the writer blocked), make them available to be read, and, when the OP’s program reads them, resume the terminal application’s write operation? It seems more likely to me this is a chosen user interface limit in the terminal application than a lower level limit.

@AnassAbidar Did you try to redirect the output from your program to a file and then compare that new file with your original file?

@EricPostpischil Read the section about canonical mode in termios(3)

@TedLyngmo the code snippet I've provided is a simplified version of what I am trying to do (implement bash here document using c) I need to read the user input from the stdin just like a normal here document does.

@AnassAbidar FWIW, I think your question is perfectly valid and you provided a good MCVE. Hence, closing the question with the provided reason above is unjustified in my opinion. However, you have received a good answer below, I don't think there is much more you can do here. If you cannot switch the terminal mode, you are out of luck, unless I miss something here.

@Ctx well it is what it is, thanks for the help. thank you everyone for the discussion learned a lot

@AnassAbidar You didn't answer my question. If you redirect the output to a file and get exactly the same content as in your original file, your program is most likely doing the right thing (except that you don't deal with -1). Have you also tried using the standard C functions fread/fwrite instead?

@Ctx: The votes to close started before OP updated with sample input. Given its current state, I might not have voted to close, but, given that it is closed, I will not vote to reopen until it is improved. It says “I looked it up” but does not say where or quote what was looked up. It says “it was because of the max size of the Kernel I/O queues,” but that is dubious. It says “any word that exceeds…”, but it is actually a line that is the issue, not a word. It says “the input gets corrupted,” but that is dubious and should be accompanied by evidence.

To handle input lines longer than 4096 bytes in C, you can switch the terminal to Non-Canonical mode (also known as Raw mode).
In Non-Canonical mode, input is available immediately without waiting for a newline, allowing you to process input that exceeds the typical buffer size.
Look at your code modified as explained above:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void setRawMode(int fd) {
    struct termios term;

    tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term);
}

void setCanonicalMode(int fd) {
    struct termios term;

    tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    term.c_lflag |= (ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term);
}

int main() {
    setRawMode(STDIN_FILENO);

    ssize_t r_bytes;
    char    buf[64];

    while ((r_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) > 0) {
        buf[r_bytes] = '\0'; 
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    setCanonicalMode(STDIN_FILENO);

    return 0;
}



Thanks for the answer! but unfortunatly I can only use these c functions: open, close, read, write,
malloc, free, perror,
strerror, access, dup, dup2,
execve, exit, fork, pipe,
unlink, wait, waitpid
any ideas if it's still fixable in my case
